# Stars under Player Ranks?

Tags: overwatch

Let me first apologize for not having a corresponding screenshot.  Hopefully I can articulate my question well enough without the visual aid.

I am still quite new to Overwatch (PS4) and have noticed certain players, of many different levels, having a Star or Stars under their player ranking.  I have seen a large bronze star and two small bronze stars to the left and right sides of the player icon so far.

I have browsed many pages of the Arqade SE but have not found any information yet.

What do these stars signify?  Does this have something to do with the "Prestige" system in Overwatch?

Note: I am at work currently and cannot access many sites.  But Good Ol' SE is unblocked haha  Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a player levels up, their portrait gets more flair every 10 levels.
[image: level 1]  [image: level 51]  [image: level 91]

At level 100, their flair resets but they earn a bronze star.
[image]

This repeats every 100 levels, so that at level 501 they've earned 5 bronze stars.

At level 601 it resets to a silver background, with 1 silver star at 701 and 5 silver stars at 1201.

At level 1301 it resets with gold backgrounds/stars.

[image: level 1801]

[Source](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Progression#Portrait_borders).

Your level is more or less just an indicator of how much you've played.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the complete breakdown @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft

Comment: Does this imply 1999 is the highest achievable level? Or just that the frame doesn't change after that?

Comment: @mephy: [No one is even close to that level](http://masteroverwatch.com/leaderboards/pc/global/mode/ranked/category/level) so we don't know for sure, but a few sources claim your border just doesn't change after that.  I personally think it's likely Blizzard will add new borders once someone gets close to those levels.

Comment: I want to believe that when someone hits 1999 their border changes to something entirely unrelated to the rest, like a shark jaw or curled-up kitten.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft When a player reaches level 100 are they able to continue playing as a level 100+ without gaining a Star or does it automatically happen?

Comment: @Mumford451: It's automatic, you can't choose your portrait background.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I wasn't insinuating that you could choose your background, I just didn't know if you could just carry on with the current border you had and progress into the 100's with no star.  A friend of mine, also on PS4, said that he "may have seen" a level 104 but he could have been mistaken.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the player's level, 1-100. Each star in addition represents 100 previous levels the player achieved. A player with 2 stars and a level of 30 is level 230.

Level is based on experience and nothing more. It has no relation to skill or any other statistics other than how much experience the player earned. This makes it mostly correlated to simply how much they've played as you get experience for winning and losing nearly the same.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer! Does this happen automatically or is the player allowed to stay at level 100 and not gain a star?

Comment: As noted in my answer, players at level 701 or 1301 will also have 1 star..

Answer (score 1):

In Overwatch when a player reaches level 100 for the first time, they receive a bronze star, they then restart at level 1. This continues until they have obtained 5 bronze stars, and they will then receive a silver etc.

Here are some Reddit posts asking the same question, with some helpful answers:

https://m.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4n27ba/a_recent_player_has_a_bronze_star_next_to_their/

https://m.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4n88il/so_does_the_star_under_someones_name_mean_they/